# ionic modal scope not working using $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl()

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to open an ionic modal just after logging in to an app. The modal is opening fine along with the data. The problem is when i attaching ng-click event corrosponding to OK or CANCEL button, it is not working.The function is not called.Maybe there is a problem with the scope. I cant figure out why..

```js
This is the controller
$scope.dummyData = NetworkDisplay.getHospitals();
        console.log($scope.dummyData.inviteToNetwork);
        if ($scope.dummyData.inviteToNetwork) {
          $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/network/modal.html', {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
          }).then(function(modal) {
              $scope.modal = modal;
              $scope.modal.show();
              console.log($scope.dummyData);
              $scope.ok = function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  if (data[i].checked === true)
                    HospitalsNetwork.set(data[i]);
                  //  console.log(data[i].checked);
                }

                $scope.modal.remove();
                $state.go('tab.networks');
              };

              $scope.cancel = function() {
                $scope.modal.remove();
                $state.go('tab.dashboard');
              };
```

```html
This is my modal.html
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
    <div class="card">
      <p class="padding">Do you like the following hospitals to be added to your network?</p>
      <!--<ul class="list">
        <li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat="hospital in dummyData.inviteToNetwork">
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox">
          </label>
          Flux Capacitor
        </li>
      </ul>-->
      <div class="list">
        <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="hospital in dummyData.inviteToNetwork" ng-model="hospital.checked">
          {{hospital.name}}
        </ion-checkbox>
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="modal-footer"> -->
      <button type="button" ng-click="ok(dummyData.inviteToNetwork)">OK</button>
      <button type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No. till now I have not found any solution. Can you get any clue? Please share me.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in the same and finally figured out that **it is not working on Ionic app but it is working on IOS emulator**. 
So finally you can't able to test Ionic modal on Ionic app till the Ionic team will fix this issue.

Comment: how you figure out this problem, if you give some clue or solution, then it will be better